# How does Eureka Server deal with this situation?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

> Eureka can be made even more resilient and available by running multiple instances and asking them to register with each other

For example, we have 3 Eureka servers:
[image]

Server A's peer instance is pointed to B, B's peer is pointed to C, C is pointed to A. **If server C is down, all registry information will be lost because Eureka uses in-memory storage**. After several minutes, server C is back on line with no registry info at all. Because B's peer is pointed to C so server B will sync with server C. Here comes the problem: C is blank now, will B delete all registry info when synchronising with C?

Comment: Each server should peer with all other servers.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1251